# Flag rows in a SAS table dated from the previous 30 days

Tags: date, sas

I have a dataset that uses dates, and I want to create two variables. One is to flag where the 'created_date' is from the last 30 days, and another to flag where the 'created_date' is from the previous 30 days. The 30 days flag works fine, but the I'm having issues with the previous 30 days. Here is my code:

```
if created_date >= intnx("day","&sysdate"d,-30,"same") then Flag_30D = 1; else Flag_30D = 0;
if created_date <= intnx("day","&sysdate"d,-30,"same") and created_date >= ("day","&sysdate"d,-60,"same") then Flag_P30D = 1; else Flag_P30D = 0;
```

Comment: Try `today()-30` to replace `intnx("day","&sysdate"d-30,"same")` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo and left out `INTNX` in second part of if *expression*.

```
created_date >= ("day","&sysdate"d,-60,"same")
```

should be

```
created_date >= INTNX("day","&sysdate"d,-60,"same")
                ^^^^^
```

Comment: Are you meaning the `intnx()` function?